# How to mock axios.create() in typescript class constructor with jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, ts-jest

I have class like this:

```
  import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

  export class Client {
  protected client!: AxiosInstance | undefined;
  constructor(config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) {
    this.client = axios.create({
      responseEncoding: "utf8",
      responseType: "json",
      ...config
    });
  }
}
```

on which I do a simple test like that:

```
import {Client} from './client';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('Client', () => {
  test('constructor', async () => { 
    new Client();
    expect(axios.create).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I have unsuccessfully tried mocking axios in various ways, aslo based on similar questions on stackoverflow, though still receiving the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Ultimately, I will have to test various member functions of Client. Any advice on getting the axios mock right would be much appreciated.

Comment: Running into this as well with just a simple API wrapper object. In testing, `axios` is undefined for some reason